# Llamar a una imagen o si no a un video o si no a un archivo

Tags: php, html, wordpress, condiciones, wordpress-theme

Tengo el siguiente código y realmente no se como hacerlo funcionar, lo he probado en una demo de un sitio que estoy haciendo, realmente nunca me vi en la necesidad de hacer algo así, pero un cliente me lo pide para ponerlo en el *loop* de las noticias, quiere que muestre un vídeo si existe o una imagen si existe y por último una imagen tipo si lo anterior no se encuentra no sabía como armarlo ya que es super inventado, de hecho es tan inventado y desastroso esta pieza de código, personalmente no la usaría para nada, ya que recarga mucho la página y no se me ocurre una mejor manera de hacerlo.

```html
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

          <img class="img-fluid d-block" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">

          <?php }

          elseif ( has_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail = null ) )

          { ?>

          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">

          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video', true); ?>" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

          </div>

          <?php }

          else ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video', false ) )

          { ?>

          <img class="img-fluid d-block" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/screenshot.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

          <?php }

          ?>
```

Comment: Deberás editar y colocar mas detalles como por ejemplo: ¿qué has intentado, que has investigado, este código funciona o qué resultado devuelve?, de modo que la comunidad tenga una idea certera de por donde comenzar a ayudarte, lee de paso [ask]

Comment: Le falta la condición a tu `elseif`.

Answer (score 0):

Falta que le indiques una condición diferente a tu `elseif`. En este caso no debe ser igual que la primera condición, lo que puedes hacer en este caso es lo siguiente:

```
/*Declaras esta función de la siguiente forma:*/
function URL_exists($url){
   $headers=get_headers($url);
   return stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
}
```

Pasas como parámetro en el primer `if` `$url = the_post_thumbnail_url();`
En el `elseif` colocas `$url2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video1', true);`

Esa función que mostré antes la saque de otra pregunta, puedes verla [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url)

Cuéntanos como te va.

Answer (score 0):

creo que usare algo mas simple que es que solo haga 2 condiciones (me olvide del elseif)... pero es como un poco meeh... me hubiese gustado hacer esto en tres condiciones pero francamente no entendí como poner condicionante al elseif... de hecho  sigo experimentando ya que ahora me gustaria hacer lo mismo en home pero en inversa si hay video, muestre video... si hay imagen, muestre imagen.

```php
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

                <img class="img-fluid img-med" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">

                <?php }

                else

                { ?>

                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video1', true); ?>" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

                </div>
                <?php }

                ?>
```